# use print an object with method toString()

Tags: java

Hellow i have a rmiclient and RMIserver and send a aray of objects Product and i want to print it as a list with toString put it show me {Product2@sad45 and i can't make it
The code is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                int pin=0;
                String tostring="";
        try {   

            String  name    =   "//Localhost/RMI_Server";
            Functions lp    =(Functions)Naming.lookup(name);
            try{
            System.out.println("Please give your Personal Code (PIN)");

                        pin=in.nextInt();
             }catch (Exception nfe) {
                    System.out.println("Input must be a number." + nfe);
                            }
            if(lp.validate(pin)){
            System.out.println("Give description of item");
            String desc=in.next();
                        Product [] p =lp.search(desc);
                        for(int i=0;i<p.length;i++){
                        tostring=(String)p[i];
            System.out.println(tostring);}
            System.out.println("Give numberCode of item you want to buy");
            String code=in.next();
            System.out.println(lp.purchase(code));
            }else{
            System.out.println("Your code is False");}
            lp.close();

        }catch (Exception   e)  {
             System.out.println("SumClient  err:    " + e); 
             System.exit(1);
         }  
            }   
        }
```

and the code of class Product is

```
import java.io.Serializable;


public class Product implements Serializable {

    private String description;
    private String serialNum;
    private float price;
    private String company;

    public Product(String description,String serialNum,float price,String company){
    this.description=description;
    this.serialNum=serialNum;
    this.price=price;
    this.company=company;       
    }

    public void set_description(String description){this.description=description;}
    public String get_description(){return description;}
    public void set_serialNum(String serialNum){this.serialNum=serialNum;}
    public String get_serialNum(){return serialNum;}
    public void set_price(float price){this.price=price;}
    public float get_price(){return price;}
    public void set_company(String company){this.company=company;}
    public String get_company(){return company;}



    public String toSting(){
        String str="Item "+ this.serialNum +" is product from "+ this.company +" price " + this.price +"E Description: ( "+ this.description +" )";
        return str;
    }


}
```

Comment: Try changing `public String toSting(){` to `public String toString(){`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from changing `public String toSting()` to `public String toString()` there is another problem in your code.

It's wrong to cast your `Product` to a `String` as you do in the line

```
tostring=(String)p[i];
System.out.println(tostring);
```

Just print the `Product` and its `toString` method is called automatically for you.

```
System.out.println(p[i])
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in your `toString` method:

```
public String toSting()
```

`toSting` instead of `toString`.

Comment: thanks i dont see it , a lot of thanks